# GitHub for windows forgot all repositories

Tags: github-for-windows

Today GitHub for Windows has suddenly forgotten all repositories on my pc. Has anyone seen anything like this? (It is the latest version, running on Win7 pro.)

Comment: Looking at your own questions I see you have been asking questions about tools. I get a bit confused about how you are thinking. Maybe you want to explain?

Comment: I retracted the vote because now I see in the faq: “We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers… a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or **software tools commonly used by programmers**; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!” Still, I guess you might get a better answer by using Github support directly, since based on this description it does not look easily reproducable.

Comment: I don’t know who gave the question the downvote. Each downvote also takes away credit from people so that’s one incentive against downvoting too much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in GitHub for Windows. At the moment I do not have more details, but I have information about how to fix it if someone else needs that. (I hope the problem will soon be gone.)

**Update: To avoid confusion I add the info I got here:**
To resolve this, you can go to %LocalAppData%\GitHub and delete the cache.db file located there. GitHub for Windows will recreate that file, and this should get things working again. You'll need to add your repositories again, though. You can drag-and-drop them in, or use the 'scan for repositories' button in the options menu.

Comment: This just happened to me yesterday...and I was just remarking how good of an app it is! :X And the 'scan for repositories' button seemed to do a great job...saved me a lot of work.

Comment: This has happened to me more than once.... and I didn't know about the "Scan for Repositories" button. Thanks! PS. You might want to highlight that part of your answer.

Comment: Just happened to me ... this seems to have fixed it so have some rep points my good man!

Answer (score 6):

Just dragging the folders from explorer to the Github window will add them back.